# Prevent rebuilding external dependency

Tags: haskell, pandoc, haskell-stack

I'm new to Haskell.

I cloned a Haskell project (pandoc) from github, and compiled it with:

```bash
stack setup
stack install --test
```

After a while, the project is built.

Now I want to build another project (pandoc-crossref), an extension to the first one and which depends on it.

There is an extra-deps entry for pandoc in stack.yaml:

```yaml
extra-deps:
  ...
  - pandoc-2.0.1.1
  ...
```

In the README.md of the pandoc-crossref project I can see:

Pandoc will also be built, *if it's not installed as a Haskell library system-wide.*

But when I try to build pandoc-crossref, pandoc is built again.

What does *installed as a Haskell library system-wide* mean? Is it possible to prevent the first project being built again? Maybe by using the --extra-lib-dirs option?

Comment: By default, `stack` builds to the `.stack-work` directory in the project folder. Use `--work-dir` to point it to a common folder across projects. I thinks this would prevent double-builds... but I haven't tested this and maybe there's a better way. Maybe ask on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/haskell-stack